# Specified type member 'DateofLastQuote' is not supported in LINQ to Entities Error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am getting the above error message in Entity Framework.

Below is the code. I am trying to join two IQueryables. DateOfLastQuote is a DateTime type that I am trying to get the value from queryand saw in another StackOverflow post to use TruncateTime to try to resolve same issue.

```cs
var revenueQuery = invoiceAllocationRepository.GetRevenuesByPartner(revenueGrid.StartDate, revenueGrid.EndDate,
    accountFilterId: revenueGrid.AccountFilter.Id,
    reviewedOnly: _context.AccountType == AccountType.System ? false : true);

revenueQuery = revenueQuery.GroupBy(r => new { r.Account, r.AccountManager, r.AccountExecutive, r.WholesaleRegionalSalesExecutive, r.PartnerName, r.PartnerOrgId, r.DateOfLastQuote}).Join(quoteQuery, r  => new { Account = r.Key.Account }, q => new { Account = q.Account },
    (r, q) => new RevenueByAccount
    {
        Account = r.Key.Account,
        AccountManager = r.Key.AccountManager,
        AccountExecutive = r.Key.AccountExecutive,
        WholesaleRegionalSalesExecutive = r.Key.WholesaleRegionalSalesExecutive,
        PartnerName = r.Key.PartnerName,
        PartnerOrgId = r.Key.PartnerOrgId,
        DateOfLastQuote = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Created)
    });

revenueQuery = revenueGrid.Sorter.Sort(revenueQuery, fieldHelper.GetName(f => f.Account));
revenueGrid.Revenues = revenueGrid.Pager.Page(revenueQuery).ToList();
```

revenueGrid.Pager calls this code below where the Exception is being thrown:

```cs
public IEnumerable<T> Page<T>(IQueryable<T> collection)
{
    var records = collection.Count();
    ....
}
```

Here is the model for the types:

```cs
public class RevenueByAccount
{
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }  
    [Display(Name = "Account")]
    public string AccountName 
    {
        get
        {
            return Account.Name;
        }
    }
    [Display(Name = "Org ID")]
    public string AccountOrgId
    {
        get
        {
            return Account.OrganizationId;
        }
    }
    [Display(Name = "Account Owner")]
    public string AccountManager { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Wholesale Account Executive")]
    public string AccountExecutive { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Wholesale Regional Sales Executive")]
    public string WholesaleRegionalSalesExecutive { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Partner")]
    public string PartnerName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Partner Org ID")]
    public string PartnerOrgId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfLastQuote  { get; set; }
    public string CSASigned { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Without implementation of your "dbfunctions.truncatetime" thingy my best bet is that this function does not return a (nullable) datetime

Comment: q.Created is a required DateTime column and there all the records in my db are populated with Dates.   But I also tried this: q.Created == null ? DateTime.Minvalue : q.created to deal with any nulls.  But same error message.

Comment: I'm referring to `DateOfLastQuote = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Created)` - the dbFunctions part, not the actual column